# why will [2..3..10] be interpreted as [2;5;8]

Tags: f#, functional-programming

When I declare the following list

```
let list = [2..3..10]
```

*F# interactive* will interpret it as a list containing `[2; 5; 8]`.
The **console output** would be:

```
let list = [2..3..10]
;;

val list : int list = [2; 5; 8]
```

What's the math behind? I don't see how the input is related to the output.

Comment: [start .. step .. stop]

Comment: What output would you expect? `[2; 5; 8; 11]`?

Comment: thank you @FoggyFinder, now it makes sense. Feel free to write an full answer, so I can mark the question as answered

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [The F# Language Specification](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/) :

> Range expressions involving expr1 .. expr2 are translated to uses of
>   the (..) operator, and those involving expr1 .. expr1 .. expr3 are
>   translated to uses of the (.. ..) operator.  The (.. ..) operator
>   generates an IEnumerable<_> for the range of values between the start
>   (expr1) and finish (expr3)  values, using an increment of expr2.

or just:

`[start .. step .. stop`]